# Using VBA to make a button on an Access form populate a textbox

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

(Note this is for a school assignment, so although there are definitely more effective ways to solve the problem I'm facing, it needs to be done in a particular fashion.)

I've created a form on Access titled 'Newborn Disease Risk Calculator.' The purpose of this form is essentially to find out what diseases a newborn child might be at risk for, based on the makeup of their DNA. Here is the desired functionality of my form:

The form has a button and two textboxes. The user inputs the NewBornID into the first textbox, then clicks the button. The second textbox then displays the diseases the newborn might be at risk for based on a SQL query. Here is the query my group mate has written (I know it is sloppy and can be rephrased):

```
    SELECT Mutation.DiseaseAssociation, Newborn.NewBornID
FROM Newborn INNER JOIN ((Mutation INNER JOIN (DNA INNER JOIN DNAMutation ON DNA.DNA_ID = DNAMutation.DNA_ID) ON Mutation.MutationID = DNAMutation.MutationID) INNER JOIN NewbornDNA ON DNA.DNA_ID = NewbornDNA.DNA_ID) ON Newborn.NewBornID = NewbornDNA.NewBornID
WHERE (((Newborn.NewBornID)=[InputNewBornID]));
```

So, being that I have little coding experience, here are my questions:

1) Is it even possible to have the results TextBox display query information in a text format?

2) If so, what is the best way to go about it? I'll post my full code below, but I can't seem to get the textbox to show any results at all. I know this is a fairly basic question, but I'm pretty knew to this, so any advice would be very helpful.

Here is my code so far for the button click:

```
Private Sub Comand0_Click()
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "SELECT Mutation.DiseaseAssociation, Newborn.NewBornID FROM Newborn INNER JOIN ((Mutation INNER JOIN (DNA INNER JOIN DNAMutation ON DNA.DNA_ID = DNAMutation.DNA_ID) ON Mutation.MutationID = DNAMutation.MutationID) INNER JOIN NewbornDNA ON DNA.DNA_ID = NewbornDNA.DNA_ID) ON Newborn.NewBornID = NewbornDNA.NewBornID WHERE Newborn.NewBornID=Forms!Calculator!txtSearch;"


Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
Me!lstDiag.RowSource = strSQL



End Sub
```

Comment: Lesson #1: Either we're talking about VBA or we're talking about VB.NET. You tagged your question as both. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mate created a query and your VBA code attempts to retrieve results from that query.  However, the query `WHERE` clause includes this condition ...

```sql
AND NewBorn.ID=sym
```

Unfortunately, `sym` is a VBA variable and the db engine doesn't know anything about it.  Seems like it would interpret `sym` to be a parameter and complain that you haven't supplied a value for that parameter.

I think you should ignore the VBA code for now and focus on revising the query.  Only after you have a working query should you go back to VBA and attempt to use it.

Create and test your query using the Access query designer.  Choose your source tables and set up the joins.  Next select your output field.  Finally create a query parameter and add a query criterion which compares `NewBorn.ID` to that parameter.  When you switch to SQL View, the relevant section of your `WHERE` clause should look similar to this ...

```sql
NewBorn.ID = [YourParameterName]
```

When you test that query, Access will display an input box asking you to supply the parameter value for *YourParameterName*.

Later when you use the query from VBA, you can supply the parameter value in your code.  But, for now, concentrate on the query.

Now that you have a working parameter query, adapt it to use the *txtSearch* text box value in place of a parameter and then use that query for your list box `Row Source`:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT Mutation.DiseaseAssociation, Newborn.NewBornID" & vbCrLf & _
"FROM Newborn INNER JOIN ((Mutation INNER JOIN (DNA INNER JOIN DNAMutation ON DNA.DNA_ID = DNAMutation.DNA_ID) ON Mutation.Mutation = DNAMutation.MutationID) INNER JOIN NewbornDNA ON DNA.DNA_ID = NewbornDNA.DNA_ID) ON Newborn.NewBornID = NewbornDNA.NewBornID" & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE (((Newborn.NewBornID)=Forms!YourFormName!txtSearch));"
Me!lstDiag.RowSource = strSQL
```

Your form includes a command button named *Command0*.  Your form's code module includes this procedure ...

```vb
Private Sub Comand0_Click()
```

But that procedure name does not match the command button name.  This works without error (Command0_Click, 2 m!) and populates the list box ...

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    'Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, strSQL As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    'Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT Mutation.DiseaseAssociation, Newborn.NewBornID FROM Newborn INNER JOIN ((Mutation INNER JOIN (DNA INNER JOIN DNAMutation ON DNA.DNA_ID = DNAMutation.DNA_ID) ON Mutation.MutationID = DNAMutation.MutationID) INNER JOIN NewbornDNA ON DNA.DNA_ID = NewbornDNA.DNA_ID) ON Newborn.NewBornID = NewbornDNA.NewBornID WHERE Newborn.NewBornID=Forms!Calculator!txtSearch;"

    'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    Me!lstDiag.RowSource = strSQL

    MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I've corrected my code above to reflect the changes. Any reason you can see why it wouldn't work now?

Comment: First tell me did that work when you tested it in the query designer --- did Access ask you to supply a value for *InputNewBornID* and then return the appropriate results?

Comment: Great!  But I forgot the goal is to set the Row Source for a list box.  So change the `WHERE` clause to this, substituting the name of your form for *YourFormName*: `WHERE Newborn.NewBornID=Forms!YourFormName!txtSearch`

Comment: That should display the query results in the list box.  But you have a text box, too, and I'm unsure what should go in there.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for the help. I've updated my code and posted it above, but it still isn't returning any results. This is literally the first time I've ever used VBA before so I'm really kind of struggling haha...

Comment: OK, but we have a lot of ground to cover.  You tested the latest query version (the one with `WHERE Newborn.NewBornID=Forms!Calculator!txtSearch`) in the query designer and it returned the results you need right?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's why I'm a bit confused on why the form doesn't work.

Comment: OK, next step: Add `Option Explicit` to the Declarations section of your form's code module (the Declarations section is at the start of the module) if it's not already there, and then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Does the code compile without error?

Comment: Then does the code even run when you click the command button?  Add a line with: `MsgBox "Hello World"` just before `End Sub`.  Do you see the message box after clicking the command button?

Comment: No results were shown, and it doesn't look like it's running. There's a message on the bottom left corner of the window that says 'Calculating. . . .'

Comment: Please upload a copy of your db file to a file sharing site and share a link.  I need to examine it to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks again. http://speedy.sh/uEbAp/Prototype.zip There is the database. It has some other tables on there that are unrelated.

Comment: See latest revision to answer.  Hope you're done now.  I know I am!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, HansUp, it worked like a charm! I really do appreciate all the help.